# Is this a correct latitude and longitude notation?

Tags: typography

Is the example below correct notation of latitude and longitude in English?

```
Coordinates:    50.0833 x 14.4667 (latitude x longitude)
```

Thanks!

(I hope the question is still in the scope of this website.)

Comment: I'm almost certain it isn't in the scope of ELU. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude

Comment: There is more than one way to correctly note lat/lon coordinates. Moreover, you need to at least include letters (N/S/E/W) to indicate which hemisphere you're referring to. For more info on this Gen. Ref. question, you can visit [here](http://www.maptools.com/UsingLatLon/Formats.html), [here](http://www.flyingclub1.org/resources/latitude_and_longitude_formats.pdf), or [here](http://www.geomidpoint.com/latlon.html).

Comment: @J.R. See Nir Levy's answer. I think that the plus and minus signs allow one to denote hemisphere, both northern and southern, as well as east or west of the Greenwich Meridian.

Comment: @J.R. Other than the N/S/E/W part, that is a great comment, and all three of those links are very fine, especially the first one!

Comment: If that's meant for "human consumption" and not machine interpretation, I suggest you pick `[NS]DD°MM.MMM',[WE]DD°MM.MMM'` which is the most common standard. Fractional degrees are almost strictly for machine use and using seconds instead of fractional minutes is a declining trend.

Comment: @FeralOink: The links I gave show that not every format requires a letter to show direction, but you still need some convention to determine which hemisphere you're in, whether it be a letter, or a minus sign. There's no way to tell if the O.P. accounted for that in the example provided.

Answer (score 2):

There are several notations to lat./long. The decimal you have is usually expressed with a comma and not an `x`. For example

> 50.0833,14.4667

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=50.0833,14.4667

However, this is not a binding standard and people can do whatever they like.

North/South hemisphere are indicated by a negative sign as do items above 180 degrees (see https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-50.0833,-14.4667)